# Работа метода replace

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется данный сценарий. Нам нужно вывести дату в терминал, при этом убрав нули.

```
import datetime as dt
d = dt.datetime.strptime('2018 02 02', '%Y %m %d') 
print(d.strftime('%Y %m %d').replace(' 0',' '))
```

Все мы знаем, что данный метод просто меняет старые значения на новые.
Если просто заменить **'0'** на **' '**, из **'2018 02 02'** получится **'218 2 2'**.
Но если в old-аргументе сделать отступ - **replace(' 0', ' ')**, то мы уже получаем то, что нужно, а именно **'2018 2 2'**. 
Как это работает? Объясните пожалуйста.

Comment: Отступ - это тоже символ, т.е. часть строки. Соответственно, когда меняете 0, то меняется каждый ноль, а если ` 0` - то меняется каждая подстрока, где перед нулём есть пробел (меняются оба символа на то, что указано во втором аргументе)

Comment: Действительно, логично. Спасибо за объяснение на столь глупый вопрос:)

Comment: Если нужно вывести дату без нулей, то можно без `strftime` просто форматированием строк обойтись, например: `'{} {} {}'.format(d.year, d.month, d.day)` или `'{d.year} {d.month} {d.day}'.format(d=d)`